# Jekyll chokes on Hologram's YAML front matter

Tags: rubygems, sass, jekyll

In order to use the [Hologram](https://github.com/trulia/hologram) CSS style-guide gem with Jekyll and Sass, I am trying to get [Jekyll](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll)'s compiler to ignore YAML front matter in multiline comments. Hologram usage looks like this:

````
/*doc
  ---
  title: Site Title
  name: site-title
  category: basics
  ---
  ```html_example <div class='site-title'>Site Title</div>
  ```
  /*/
````

Jekyll throws an error when it encounters the dashes:

```
WARNING on line 16 of /Users/marcy/Sites/Substantial/corpsite-2014/corpsite-jekyll/assets/_sass/modules/header/_header.sass:
This selector doesn't have any properties and will not be rendered.

error assets/_sass/screen.sass (Line 10 of assets/_sass/modules/header/_header.sass: 
  Invalid CSS after "-": expected number or function, was "--")
```

Has anyone gotten around this before? We had Hologram working before converting stylesheets to Sass. Which makes me think it's the Sass compiler's fault.

Installed Gems:

- Hologram 1.1.0
- Jekyll 2.0.3
- Sass 3.2.19
- Compass 0.12.2
- Jekyll-Compass 1.0.6

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding the [raw tag](https://gist.github.com/phaer/1020852) to your `plugins` folder as `raw.rb`, and then wrapping your code like so:

````
{% raw %}
/*doc
---
title: Site Title
name: site-title
category: basics
---
```html_example <div class='site-title'>Site Title</div>
```
/*/
{% endraw %}
````

Keep in mind this won't work if jekyll is built with safe enabled (e.g. on github pages) because custom plugins are not allowed.

Comment: This isn't working for me once I add the plugin. I get the same errors as before. Is this supposed to work in Jekyll's native Sass compiler?

Comment: No, this won't work with the native compiler because that doesn't parse `liquid` tags. This will work for files that are processed by a jekyll generator or similar.

Comment: Bummer. That doesn't answer the question then. I had hope!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I don't think you can actually accomplish what you are trying to do with your current tool chain.